# Replace an empty map with map data from a variable in yq

Tags: yaml, yq

Using mikefarah/yq (4.25.3) I am trying to replace an empty map in a yaml file with a map stored in a string.

This is the map data:

```
RESOURCES=$(cat <<EOF
limits:
  cpu: 4000m
  memory: 3600Mi
requests:
  cpu: 500m
  memory: 900Mi
EOF
)
```

And this is what I am trying to execute:

```
yq -i ".cluster.resources = \"${RESOURCES}\"" values.yaml
```

As a result I get a multiline string (instead of a map):

```
resources: |-
    limits:
      cpu: 4000m
      memory: 3600Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 500m
      memory: 900Mi
```

How do I insert a map instead?

```
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: 4000m
    memory: 3600Mi
  requests:
    cpu: 500m
    memory: 900Mi
```

Comment: What is the content of `${RESOURCES}` and what is your desired result (minimal examples)?

Comment: The content is shown above, I'll edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`env()`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/env-variable-operators) operator to load environment variable into yq:

```bash
RESOURCES=$(cat <<EOF
limits:
  cpu: 4000m
  memory: 3600Mi
requests:
  cpu: 500m
  memory: 900Mi
EOF
)  yq --null-input ".cluster.resources = env(RESOURCES)"
```

Will produce:

```yaml
cluster:
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 4000m
      memory: 3600Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 500m
      memory: 900Mi
```